# Couldn't update nested attributes in Rails 4.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, strong-parameters

I migrated my Rails from 3.2 to Rails 4.2.6. I am having 2 tables where **report :has_many => icons**. I added strong parameters for report and icon_attributes. The create functionality is working fine and when coming to update functionality, I am able to update reports but couldn't update icons, instead new icon is created every time it hits update action.
This is my code:

report.rb:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :icons, -> { order 'position_id ASC'}
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :icons, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:icon].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

icon.rb:

```
class Icon < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :report
end
```

reports_controller:

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @report.update_attributes(report_params)
        @report.save
        format.html { redirect_to(user_reports_url, :notice => 'Report was successfully updated.') }
        format.json { render :json => { :success => true, :report_id => @report.id, :report_title => @report.title, :icon_array => @report.icons, :redirect => report_url(@report.id) } }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @report.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def report_params
    params.require(:report).permit(:title, :comments, :remarks,{:icons_attributes => [:id, :icon, :rotation, :top, :_destroy]})
  end
```

I have seen the log by putting *puts* in the controller, the icons are inserting at **@report.update_attributes(report_params)** step and this is the log:

> Processing by ReportsController#update as JSON   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓", "report"=>{"title"=>"title1", "comments"=>"This is a comment",
>   "icons_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"", "icon"=>"market_indicator",
>   "rotation"=>"0", "top"=>"",  "_destroy"=>"false"}, "id"=>"87"}
>
> Report Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "reports".* FROM "reports" WHERE
>   "reports"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "reports"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id",
>   87]]
>   SQL (1.6ms)  INSERT INTO "icons" ("icon", "rotation", "top")
>   VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["icon", "market"], ["rotation", "0"], ["top", ""],
>   ["left", ""]]    (12.0ms)  commit transaction
>    ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy

I have put log as:

```
  def update
    puts @report.icons.inspect
    respond_to do |format|
     .....
  end
```

it resulted as:

Icon Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "icons".* FROM "icons" WHERE "icons"."report_id" = ?  ORDER BY position_id ASC  [["report_id", 91]]

## `<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Icon id: 204, report_id: 91, icon: "asking_price", rotation: "", top: "150", left: "165">]>`

Comment: Could you post the parameters being passed in to your update action?

Comment: As I posted in the question, I am using report_params as the parameters for update action.

Comment: I meant post the params from the logs. They should look like `Parameters: {"report"=> { "title" => "blah", "icons_attributes" => { etc. } }}`

Comment: `icons_attributes` should be an array I think.

Comment: I added in the log plz check

Answer (score 0):

Your `"icon_attributes"` is not passing the id of the icon along.

```
"icons_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"", "icon"=>"market_indicator", "rotation"=>"0", "top"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "id"=>"87"}
```

You'll notice the id is blank.  Since the id is blank rails thinks it is a new record and thus creates a new icon.  The error lies in how you have made your form.

Comment: Before the update I am printing icons, id is listed fine. I updated in the question, please check.

Comment: Yes but the update action does not have the id as shown in your log.